# как сверстать текст с изображением в качестве бекграунда для букв

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Собственно как можно сверстать вот такую надпись как в макете, идет бекграунд картинкой для слова (букв)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью `background-clip: text`.

```css
.block {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/FArAloZ.jpg');
}

.block-text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0); /*Обязательно*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="block-text">Какой-то текст<br>И ещё строка</span>
</div>
```